# Is there any way to synchronize workspace changes between monitors in Mac OS 10.11 (El Capitan)?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, osx-spaces, osx-el-capitan

Is there a simple method for synchronizing workspace changes between multiple monitors on MacOS **with the *'displays have separate Spaces'* options enabled**?

I.e. I have an equal number of Spaces for both displays and I want cmd + 1 to switch to workspaces 1 & 6 (assuming 5 workspaces on both monitors). Having to manually synchronize them is cumbersome.

ps. "Split View" is the reason I'd like to enable the separate Spaces option so if there is a way to make split view work with the option disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used El Capitan much at all, so I don't know if there's another way, but I've used
[TotalSpaces](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com) in previous OS's with the `Fullscreen` feature.

TotalSpaces can sync spaces, even if the `Displays have separate spaces` is on. There is a `Sync grids` option in the `Layout` tab of the preferences (screenshots below).

---

Sadly:

> TotalSpaces2 versions 2.3.5 and above have support for OSX 10.11 El Capitan, but cannot run on a normally configured machine due to system integrity protection, a new security feature in El Capitan.
>
> [This article](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/elcapitan) will tell you how to configure your machine by modifying the new setting, so that you can run TotalSpaces2.

---

It's also cool and good to know that you can have uneven amount of spaces in each screen, like I have in my setup.

For example: If I jump from space 1 to space 5, only my `imac` space will change. If I then jump to space 2, both screens will switch to that space, as it's available in both.

[image]
[image]